# Error with Bootstrap 3 Collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Well i have a page that shows products (entertaiment products) and a list of members of the products (a tango orchestra, or a dancing couple, for example). I want the info of the members to be displayed on accordions for each product. For example, if the "Tango Orchestra" have 3 members i want an accordion with 3 "tabs" to show those members, and the same for the rest of the products... I use AngularJS to generate dynamically the accordions and the id's of those accordions and the tabs associated to those accordions (i can't hardcode those id's because the list of products come from a database and i can't know how much products i will have) and the problem i have is that when i click a title tab it shows the content but hide the titles of all of the tabs, so i can't change tabs to see the others members info. I'll notice that for some reason a `in` class is beign added to my `div` with the `panel-heading` class and i don't know why.
I'll left you the html and js files im using:

productos.html (the part of the problem):

```
<!-- Contenido -->
    <div id="main-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-content" ng-repeat="r in rubros">
                <h2 class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-lg-push-5 rubro" id="{{r.rubro | lowercase}}" style="font-weight: 700;">{{r.rubro | uppercase}}</h2>
                <div class="col-xs-12 wrapper" ng-repeat="t in tipos | filter: {rubro: r.rubro}">
                    <div class="row row-content">
                        <h3 id="{{t.tipo | lowercase}}" class="tipo">{{t.tipo | uppercase}}</h3>
                        <!-- Tabs -->
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li ng-repeat="prod in productos | filter: {tipo: t.tipo}"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#{{prod.nombre | IdFilter}}">{{prod.nombre}}</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- Tabs Contenido -->
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade row row-content" id="{{prod.nombre | IdFilter}}" ng-repeat="prod in productos | filter: {tipo: t.tipo}">
                                <!-- Videos -->
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
                                    <h4>VIDEOS:</h4>
                                    <iframe ng-repeat="video in prod.videos" ng-src="{{getIFrameSrc(video.link)}}" ng-show="prod.videos.length > 0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                                    <p ng-show="prod.videos.length == 0">No hay vídeos de este producto</p>
                                </div> <!-- Fin Videos -->
                                <h4 class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">INTEGRANTES:</h4>
                                <!-- Accordion -->
                                <div id="accordion{{accordionId(prod.nombre)}}" class="panel-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                                    <!-- Items -->
                                    <div ng-repeat="integrante in prod.integrantes" class="panel panel-default">
                                        <!-- Titulo del item -->
                                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-{{integrante.nombre | IdFilter}}{{accordionId(prod.nombre)}}">
                                            <h3 class="panel-title">
                                               <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion{{accordionId(prod.nombre)}}" href="#{{integrante.nombre | IdFilter}}{{accordionId(prod.nombre)}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="{{integrante.nombre | IdFilter}}">{{integrante.nombre}} {{integrante.apellido}}</a>
                                            </h3>
                                        </div> <!-- Fin Titulo -->
                                        <!-- Contenido del item -->
                                        <div id="{{integrante.nombre | IdFilter}}{{accordionId(prod.nombre)}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-{{integrante.nombre | IdFilter}}{{accordionId(prod.nombre)}}" role="tabpanel">
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <p>{{integrante.resenia}}</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div> <!-- Fin Contenido -->
                                    </div> <!-- Fin Item -->
                                </div> <!-- Fin Accordion -->
                                <p class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" ng-class="{'col-sm-pull-6': prod.videos.length > 0}" style="padding-top: 10px;">{{prod.resenia}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

ProductosController.js:

```
(function(){

    var module = angular.module("tangoInfinito");

    var ProductosController = function($scope, $sce, ProductosService) {

        $scope.getIFrameSrc = function(link) {
            return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(link + "?controls=2");
        };

        function idAsignado(lista, producto) {
            var listaLength = lista.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < listaLength; i++) {
                if (lista[i].producto === producto) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        };

        var listaIdAccordions = [];

        var accordionNumber = 0;

        $scope.accordionId = function(prodNombre) {  
            if(!idAsignado(listaIdAccordions, prodNombre)) {
                accordionNumber++;
                listaIdAccordions.push({
                    producto: prodNombre,
                    id: ("accordion" + accordionNumber)
                });
                return accordionNumber;
            }
            else {
                var largo = listaIdAccordions.length;
                for(var i = 0; i < largo; i++) {
                    if(listaIdAccordions[i].producto === prodNombre) {
                        var temp = listaIdAccordions[i].id;
                        var id = temp.slice(temp.length - 1, temp.length);
                        return id;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var armarLista = function($rubros, $tipos) {
            var lista = [];
            var rubrosTemp = $rubros.slice(0);
            var tiposTemp = $tipos.slice(0);

            for(var i = 0; i < rubrosTemp.length; i++) {

                var rubro = rubrosTemp[i].rubro.toUpperCase();

                lista.push( {descripcion: rubro, isHeader: true} ); 
                for(var j = 0; j < tiposTemp.length; j++) {
                    if(tiposTemp[j].rubro === rubrosTemp[i].rubro) {
                        lista.push( {descripcion: tiposTemp[j].tipo, isHeader: false} );
                    }
                }
            }
            return lista;
        };

        var getDatosFromService = function() {
            ProductosService.getDatos().success(function(response) {

                $scope.navbarList = armarLista(response["rubros"], response["tipos"]);
                $scope.productos = response["productos"];
                $scope.rubros = response["rubros"];
                $scope.tipos = response["tipos"];
            });
        }

        getDatosFromService();
    };

    module.controller("ProductosController", ProductosController);
})();
```

IdFilter.js:

```
(function() {

    var module = angular.module("tangoInfinito");

    var IdFilter = function() {
        return function(item) {
            var id = "";
            id = item.toLowerCase();
            id = id.replace(/\s/g, "-");
            return id;
        };
    };

    module.filter("IdFilter", IdFilter);

})();
```

And the behavior i was talking about:

initial state

[image: initial state]

when i click on tabs titles

[image: when i click on tabs titles]

I would be very thankfull for any help that help me to debug or fix this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: create jsfiddle to understand issue

Comment: how i create a jsfiddle with angular? i took the data from a local database too... how solve that?

Comment: you can include angular js file as external and create fiddle. see example http://jsfiddle.net/halirgb/Lvc0u55v/

Comment: i am getting a syntax error over and over and i have fixed that error...

Comment: here is my jsfiddle... i don't know how to make it work... https://jsfiddle.net/ndL03wxp/ @Bhumi

Comment: jsfiddle working https://jsfiddle.net/ndL03wxp/7/ ... but don't reproduce the error... it works fine on jsfiddle... @BhumiShah. So i think that is something in my computer... i don't know where to keep looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i have found the answer... the incorrect behavior is because i have a script in the end of the page that add `active in` classes to the first div of the tabs section to get the first tab show but also add those classes to the `div` with the `panel-heading` class, and because of that the collapse script won't work fine... the solution i just found it just remove the class with the `removeClass` method from `jQuery`. Here is the code of the script:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                //Tomo el nodo al que luego le agrego li según correspondan
                //<li class="dropdown-header">Rubro</li> Para los rubros
                //<li><a href="#tipo">Tipo</a></li> 
                var lista = $("ul.dropdown-menu");

                var navbarProductosLista = undefined;

                //Chequea hasta que la variable navbarList de ProductosController esta asignada
                function checkVariable() {
                    //Toma la variable navbarList del scope de ProductosController
                    //para agregar la lista de manera dinámica
                    navbarProductosLista = angular.element($("[ng-controller=ProductosController]")).scope().navbarList;

                    if(navbarProductosLista != undefined) {
                        for(var i = 0; i < navbarProductosLista.length; i++) {
                            if(navbarProductosLista[i].isHeader === true) {
                                var nodo = $("<li><a href='productos.html#" + navbarProductosLista[i].descripcion.toLowerCase() + "'>" +  navbarProductosLista[i].descripcion + "</a></li>");
                                nodo.children().addClass("dropdown-header");
                                lista.append(nodo);
                            }
                            else {
                                var nodo = $("<li><a href='productos.html#" + navbarProductosLista[i].descripcion.toLowerCase() + "'>" +  navbarProductosLista[i].descripcion + "</a></li>");
                                lista.append(nodo);
                            }
                        }
                        clearInterval(id);
                    }

                    $("ul li:first-child")
                    .addClass("active");

                    //This is the line that causes the problem
                    $(".tab-content div:first-child")
                    .addClass("in active");

                    //And this the line that fix it
                    $(".panel-heading")
                    .removeClass("in active");
                };

                var id = setInterval(checkVariable, 250);
            });
        </script>
```